# Ruby On Rails Console Is Not Starting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in`'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in`'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in`require_command!'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `'

Comment: Add the whole stacktrace/error.

Comment: ?? I Didnot Understant Please Help Me

Comment: The whole error you're receiving

Comment: Please paste the whole error to debug

Comment: PG::ConnectionBad

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `gem 'rb-readline'` to your project. It appears you don't have the capability to handle console interaction, and that gem should provide it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gem file.
install relevant rvm
use command - rvm use 'Your_version'